# How to make GitHub show Java as the programing language on a repository?

Tags: github

I'm working on a repository in GitHub that has Java code example including HTML, CSS, Javascript, Typescript.

I wanted GitHub to mark/show "Java" as the primary programming language of the repository but shows up as HTML.

The below did not help

1. I tried adding **.gitattributes** to my repo with below lines, but did not help. Help from blog [How to Change Repo Language in GitHub](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-change-repo-language-in-github-c3e07819c5bb)

   ```
   * linguist-vendored
   *.java linguist-language=Java
   ```
2. Tried this [gitattributes / Java.gitatttributes](https://github.com/alexkaratarakis/gitattributes/blob/master/Java.gitattributes)

[image]

Comment: Is this about Git or about Git**Hub**? These are very different things. Git itself doesn't know anything about languages.

Comment: just throwing it out there - the `Java.gitattributes` you link to doesn't do anything with `linguist-vendored`.

Comment: Thanks @Thomas updated to "GitHub".

Comment: Have you tried a Maven vendored code path? https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/lib/linguist/vendor.yml

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get GitHub mark my project appropriately.

1) Add a new file named `.gitattributes` at the root level, to your master branch in your repository

2) Add the below lines to the file

```
*.java linguist-detectable=true
*.js linguist-detectable=false
*.html linguist-detectable=false
*.xml linguist-detectable=false
```

Save and refresh your browser. You will be able to see your Java project marked correctly. Also you can add more types of files to be ignored.

[image]

[The example .gitattributes file for my Java Examples project on GitHub](https://github.com/ksurendra/java-examples/blob/master/.gitattributes)

[More details in this blog post](https://medium.com/techinpieces/how-to-change-github-repository-language-for-java-projects-797b808adaee)